# How to sync Visual Foxpro dbfs with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, dbf

I'm trying to sync a legacy application (which stores data in VisualFoxpro dbfs) to MySQL or SqlServer 2005.  This will allow us to see certain information online.  I need this sync at least twice a day.

How can I do this?

Comment: How much data (records estimate), how many tables?  How large is the raw data (.dbf, .cdx, .fpt) on the drive where its stored?

Comment: It's about 300,000 records, around 20MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any off-the-shelf software to handle this, but it would not be difficult using [python](http://python.org), [my dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf), and one of the [MySQL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) packages.

Once you have the script written, add it to the system scheduler to run as often as you need.

Very rough example:

```
import dbf
import MySQLdb

legacy_table = dbf.Table(r'\some\path\to\table.dbf')

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='some_server', user='some_body', passwd='complexicate me!', db='the_db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cusor.execute('command to recreate table') # yes, my SQL is weak  :(
                                           # other option is to use REPLACE below, and skip this step

for record in legacy_table:
    cursor.execute(
        'insert into table_name values (%s, %s, %s)',
        args=(record.name, record.age, record.comment)
        )

# for performance, executemany is better -- I _think_ this will work
cursor.executemany(
    'insert into table_name values (%s, %s, %s)',
    args = [(record.name, record.age, record.comment) for record in legacy_table])
```

This will hopefully get you started.  Feel free to ask more questions.